# Как вывести имя вместо id, SQL?

Tags: mysql

Для изображенной схемы БД необходимо составить запрос, который вернет список всех счетов. Для каждого счета выбрать поля номер счета, дата счета, имя клиента и имя клиента, на которого ссылается клиент текущего счета. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT
    Invoices.id, Invoices.Billing_date,
    Customers.Name, Customers.Reffered_ID
FROM second_test.Invoices, second_test.Customers
WHERE Invoices.Customer_ID = Customers.id;
```

Подскажите, как вывести имя клиента на которого ссылается клиент (в данном запросе выводится id вместо имени)?

Comment: Используйте join как вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо таблицу Customers присоединить через `LEFT JOIN` указанием связи `Referrer_ID`

```
SELECT
    INV.id, 
    INV.Billing_date,
    CUS.Name AS CUSTOMER_NAME, 
    REF.Name AS REFERRER_NAME
FROM 
    second_test.Invoices INV
INNER JOIN 
    second_test.Customers CUS ON INV.Customer_ID = CUS.id
LEFT JOIN 
    second_test.Customers REF ON CUS.Referred_ID = REF.id
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо.